# Adding dynamic column using trinidad by clicking on a link in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, trinidad

```
    <trh:tableLayout width="25%" borderWidth="3" cellSpacing="5"
        halign="center"    >
        <h:commandLink action="#{dataBean.setInitial}" value="ShowView">
        </h:commandLink>
        <trh:rowLayout  shortDesc="head">
            <tr:panelHeader size="4" text="Id" />

            <tr:forEach var="row"  begin="0" end="#{dataBean.size}" items="#{dataBean.dataList}">
            <tr:outputText value="#{row.id}" rendered="#{row.editable}"/>

            </tr:forEach>
        </trh:rowLayout>
        <trh:rowLayout>
            <tr:panelHeader size="4" text="Name" />
            <tr:forEach var="row" begin="0" end="#{dataBean.size}" items="#{dataBean.dataList}">
                <tr:outputText value="#{row.text}" rendered="#{row.editable}" />

            </tr:forEach>

        </trh:rowLayout>
    </trh:tableLayout>
```

I am using trh tags in trinidad to display row wise data ..

### and output is like...

Show View

---

ID        2           1

Name      raj      Narendra

I want to add a dynamic column in row wise by clicking on link show view..If i click back on show view it should hide that column...Please suggest me how to add rendered attribute and where it should be..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

Something like this:

```
<tr:commandLink action="#{dataBean.setInitial}" value="ShowView" id="showHideLink"/>
<tr:table value="#{dataBean.dataList}" var="row" id="itemTable" partialTrigger="showHideLink">
    <tr:column rendered="#{row.column1Visible}" id="itemCol">
        <tr:outputText value="#{row.text1}"/>
    </tr:column>
        <tr:column rendered="#{row.column2Visible}" id="itemCol">
    <tr:outputText value="#{row.text2}"/>
    </tr:column>  
</tr:table>
```

In order to get the table to refresh when you click the link, set the partialTrigger property of the table to the id of the button.

To control the visibility of the columns you'll need to use the objects in the dataList.
For example, you could have the fields column1Visible and column2Visible in those objects (with public getters and setters).